# Sequelize Error : Column names in each table must be unique

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I had an error in Sequelize with a foreign key not matching a column name. Checking the DB, I saw that the column 'WokflowId' was named 'WorkflowID', so I changed the name in the Sequelize model.

It looks like this

```
'use strict';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../util/database');

const WorkflowsAccessRights = sequelize.define('Workflows_AccessRights', {  
  id:{
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  WorkflowID: Sequelize.BIGINT,
  GroupID: Sequelize.BIGINT,
  Enabled: Sequelize.INTEGER
},{
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true,
});


module.exports = WorkflowsAccessRights
```

But now that I changed the column name to get the right one, I get this error

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'WorkflowId' in table 'Workflows_AccessRights' is specified more than once.

Except that, no column has this name now... Did I miss something in the setup or is there a way to freeze the column name?

Comment: If I were to guess I'd guess that Sequelize is using a case-sensitive model on a database whose default collation is case-insensitive. i.e.: Sequelize cannot match the column named `WorkflowID` in its model, so tries to recreate it, but SQL Server refuses because it still has the old column named `WorkflowId`.

Comment: But the name in the sql db in WorkflowID. So it means, Sequelize must be camelCasing my column name...

Comment: I already tried to add camelCase: false, but it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after searching in the whole project. I found out that I was calling a foreignKey on WorkflowId. Therefore Sequelize tried to create a new column called WorkfklowId and had a bug doing it. I just renamed the foreignKey and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following link will be helpful for you. It asks to put `IF NOT EXISTS` to the SQL script as follows,

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE Name = 'ColumnName' 
              AND object_id = OBJECT_ID('YourTableName'))
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableName
      ADD ColumnName INT    -- or whatever it is
END
```

[Check this link. It is the same question that you have asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741927/column-names-in-each-table-must-be-unique)

Comment: Except I'm using Sequelize to sync with the db, so I'm not able to add a script to it.